# Scala nested maps - how to process?

Tags: scala, csv, nested, maps

Here is my nested map example with the data as literals. The program works as intended.

```
    var x = scala.collection.mutable.Map(
        ("Early", Map(("a", 1),  ("b", 2))), 
        ("Late",  Map(("x", 24), ("y", 25))))

for (ticker <- x.keys) {
    val trades = x(ticker)
    for (tradetime <- trades.keys) {
        val tradetotal = trades(tradetime)
        println(ticker + " | " + tradetime + " | " + tradetotal)
    }
    println(ticker + " | " + trades)
}
```

However, I want to eliminate the literals and read the above values from a csv file. Here is the csv:

```
Early,a,1 
Early,b,2
Late,x,24
Late,y,25
```

Here is the code to read the csv and print out the values in a way similar to the above program with literals.

```
  val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("mapt.csv")
  val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder

  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}")
    var tmp = cols(0)   // s"${cols(0)}"

    val inner = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]
    inner(cols(1)) = cols(2).toInt
    println(inner)

    val outer = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, String]
    outer(cols(0)) = inner
    println(outer)

  }
  bufferedSource.close
```

My code does not work. I’m struggling to find guidance on how to process nested maps. I am learning Scala. Grateful for any suggestions to create nested maps from csv file data.

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("mapt.csv").getLines()
val row = lines.map(_.split(",").map(_.trim))
val outerMap=row.groupBy(_.head)
val result = outerMap.map{case (key,values)=> 
  key-> values.map(v=>(v(1)->v(2))).toMap}
```

Comment: Nice. I think using `mapValues()` would simplify the final line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, Arnon. Your last line puzzled me. However, it showed me a new technique that helped me solve the problem. Here is my working code:

```
  val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("mapt.csv")
  val builder = StringBuilder.newBuilder

  for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
    val cols = line.split(",").map(_.trim)
    println(s"${cols(0)}|${cols(1)}|${cols(2)}")

    val outerMap = Map(cols(0) -> Map(cols(1) -> cols(2).toInt))
    println("outerMap looks like this: " + outerMap)
    println("Accessing the lowest-level value: " + outerMap(cols(0))(cols(1)))  
  }
  bufferedSource.close
```

My thinking is flawed, I know. The above approach is a copy of how I nest associative arrays in awk. One day I'll start thinking in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

To specifically address your compilation error:

You're stating that the `outer` map has a `String` key and and `String` value.

But later when you do `outer(cols(0)) = ???` you're saying "I want to put this value at the key `cols(0)`".

So the compiler complains that what you're trying to insert into the map is of a different type than the expected `String`.

Note: mutability is discouraged in Scala. Unless you really need to, you can write the same kind of code using immutable collections.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and advice, mfirry. I need all I can get. As you can see, I'm still crawling, haven't yet started to walk. One day I'll be a great Scala programmer!